# MySQL select items that do not have a specific category

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `cart_item` and `cart_item_category`.

Both tables have an `itemref` that is used to join them.

Now, there can be multiple of one `itemref` in the `cart_item_category` table because each item can belong to more than one category.

The second field in the `cart_item_category` table is `catid`.  Now I want to select all items in `cart_item` that do not have an associated `catid` of 63.

I cannot figure out how to write that query.

I also only want to show food items.

So here is the start of my query.

I know it is not right because I am simply returning all records not equal to 63.

I only want to show records that do not have an associated `catid` of 63.

```
SELECT ci.pid, ci.itemref, ci.name, cic.catid 
FROM cart_item ci 
JOIN cart_item_category cic USING (itemref) 
WHERE ci.isfood = 1 AND cic.catid != 63;
```

Comment: I do not know if my query is correct in mysql, but it would be something like SELECT ci.pid, ci.itemref, ci.name FROM cart_item ci WHERE NOT EXIST (select FROM cart_item_category cic WHERE cic.itemref = ci.itemref AND cic.catid = 63);

Comment: i think the answer from @Egl may be your answer.

Comment: This is a simple exclusion join, but if you're still struggling, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Egl, if you change it to 'EXISTS' and make it an answer, I will accept it.  That worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be:

```
SELECT ci.pid, ci.itemref, ci.name 
FROM cart_item ci 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select FROM cart_item_category cic 
    WHERE cic.itemref = ci.itemref 
    AND cic.catid = 63);
```